# Why does shell=True eat my subprocess.Popen stdout?

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen

It seems that using shell=True in the first process of a chain somehow drops the stdout from downstream tasks:

```
p1 = Popen(['echo','hello'], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen('cat', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p2.communicate()
# outputs correctly ('hello\n', None)
```

Making the first process use shell=True kills the output somehow...

```
p1 = Popen(['echo','hello'], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
p2 = Popen('cat', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p2.communicate()
# outputs incorrectly ('\n', None)
```

shell=True on the second process doesn't seem to matter.  Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you pass `shell=True`, Popen expects a single string argument, not a list.  So when you do this:

```
p1 = Popen(['echo','hello'], stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

What happens is this:

```
execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "echo", "hello"], ...)
```

That is, it calls `sh -c "echo"`, and `hello` is effectively ignored (technically it becomes a positional argument to the shell).  So the shell runs `echo`, which prints `\n`, which is why you see that in your output.

If you use `shell=True`, you need to do this:

```
p1 = Popen('echo hello', stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! For posterity, here's the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

On Unix, with shell=True: If args is a sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:

`Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`

Comment: very poorly documented, IMHO