# Using curl in Popen in Python

Tags: python, curl, popen

I run this curl command in the unix shell and it works (see below). I was able to redirect the returned data to a file but now I want to process the data in my code instead of wasting a bunch of space in a file.

```
curl -k -o outputfile.txt 'obfuscatedandVeryLongAddress'
#curl command above, python representation below
addr = "obfuscatedandVeryLongAddress"
theFile = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-k", addr], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

theFile.stdout is empty after this. The data returned in the curl command should be something like 4,000 lines (verified when running the command in the shell). Is the size breaking theFile.stdout? Am I doing something else wrong? I tried using:

```
out, err = theFile.communicate()
```

and then printing the out variable but still nothing

edit: formatting and clarification

Comment: Why don't you use the `requests` library? Or system default `urllib` ?

Comment: related: [Why does shell=True eat my subprocess.Popen stdout?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10661457/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `shell=True`.

`theFile = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-k", addr], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)`

Should work.

If you do `shell=True`, you should pass a string. Otherwise, what you're actually doing is passing those arguments `-k`, and `addr` as arguments to the shell. So if your shell is `sh`, what you're doing is `sh 'curl' -k addr`.

Answer (score 0):

Eugene's is a direct answer to your question, but I thought I'd add one on using the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library, since it will require less code and be easier to read for anyone that needs to look at your code (and has the benefit of being cross-platform).

```
import requests

response = requests.get('longaddress', verify=False)
print response.text
```

If the response is json, you can automatically convert it to a python object

```
print response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the curl command in a string like:

```
theFile = subprocess.Popen('curl -k {}'.format(addr), stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, shell = True)
```

Or you can remove the shell argument:

```
theFile = subprocess.Popen(["curl", "-k", addr], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
```

Or you could use the pycurl module to use libcurl library directly and skip the whole additional process.