# Strange subprocess behavior

Tags: python, subprocess

```
subprocess.call(["find", ".", "-exec", "sh", "-c", "echo testFirst", ";"])
subprocess.call(["find", ".", "-exec", "sh", "-c", "echo testSecond", ";"], shell=True)
subprocess.call(["find . -exec sh -c 'echo testThird' \\;"], shell=True)

subprocess.call(["find", ".", "-exec", "sh", "-c", "touch testFirst", ";"])
subprocess.call(["find", ".", "-exec", "sh", "-c", "touch testSecond", ";"], shell=True)
subprocess.call(["find . -exec sh -c 'touch testThird' \\;"], shell=True)
```

The following outputs:

```
testFirst
testFirst
testFirst
.
./test.py
./data
testThird
testThird
testThird
.
./test.py
./testFirst
./data
```

And only `testFirst` and `testThird` files are created.

What is the explanation of the behaviour?

I would assume output of `testFirst`, `testSecond`, `testThird` as well as the three files being created.

Comment: Why do you need the first 4 arguments?

Comment: This isn't my actual code, I've just narrowed it down to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10661488/1663462

> When you pass shell=True, Popen expects a single string argument, not
>   a list.

...........