# Send SIGINT to subprocess and also see output

Tags: python

In a celery task, I am launching a `subprocess` and need (1) to  be able to send a `SIGINT` while (2) also having access to the subprocess's stdout and stderr. I am able to do one or the other, but not both simultaneously.

I can send `SIGINT` when the command in subprocess is given as a list, or as a string prepended with bash:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(,
    [sys.executable, "-m", path.to.module, myarg1, myarg2, ...],    # also works with f"/bin/bash -c {sys.executable} -m path.to.module {myarg1} {myarg2} ..."
    stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False
)
```

As far as I understand, both options are ultimately launching bash and it seems that only a running bash will react to `SIGINT`.

Conversely, running "python -m ..." means my program no longer reacts to the `SIGINT`, but on the other hand it allows me to start seeing the stdout/stderr and logging inside my python program:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(,
    f"{sys.executable} -m path.to.module {myarg1} {myarg2} ..."
    stdin=sys.stdin, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False
)
```

With the above, now I'm no longer able to send `SIGINT` to my program but the logging is working.

How can I get both things to work at the same time? I've played around with `shell=True` and the various stdin/out/err tweaks, but no luck.

EDIT: With the top form (command as a list) and adding `signal.signal()` to my program in `path.to.module` I am able to both receive the SIGINT as well as see some output.

Comment: The first form does not run bash or any other shell, but it is much much better especially from a security perspective.  In the second form the shell is probably swallowing the interrupt signal.  When you say you need access to the subprocess's output, what code handles it, and what results do you see?

Comment: Setting the command as a list, or as a string prepended with "/bin/bash" (as commented on that line) means it's running bash no?

And yes, the bottom form feels like the shell is swallowing the signal.

I need to see the output of that `path.to.module` program, which is simply logging to stdout/err and file. No other code needs to handle it, I just need to see it. With the top form I can't see it, with the bottom form I can see it but I lose the ability to send `SIGINT`.

Comment: "Setting the command as a list" does not in and of itself cause a shell to be run, unless the path to the bash executable is the first element of that list. `sys.executable` is the Python executable, not the bash executable.

Comment: I see now. I was basing it off a comment found on this post but I'm seeing that's only true when shell = True:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661457/why-does-shell-true-eat-my-subprocess-popen-stdout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> need to be able to send a SIGINT ...

I disagree with the premise.

I believe the need is to "stop a running process" in some
sensible way, and INT, USR1, HUP or other signals might suffice.
The key is to have a signal handler active for the relevant signal.

The other detail is "access to ... stdout", which is
entirely reasonable. That is, we do not want *abrupt*
termination, but rather we want printf(3) buffers to be
flushed by write(2) syscalls prior to termination.

So the crux is that we want child process (or maybe process group)
to be sent a signal it is expecting, and then handle the
signal nicely.

---

`bash` traps certain signals so that is definitely a concern.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ... , shell=False)
```

> ... both options are ultimately launching bash

No, at least not in this instance.
The `False` argument means that `bash` is not involved here.

---

Consider `def`ining a `handler`, and then doing

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, handler)
```

The handler might choose to call `sys.exit`,
in order to flush stdout buffers.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal

Comment: `path.to.module` is a while loop which breaks on SIGINT. Idc which signal it uses to break the loop, the issue is that it only detects the signal with the top form. But with that top form I stop seeing any of its output. Conversely, with the bottom form I can see the output but lose the ability to detect the SIGINT. Also, the command in the top form is a list or a string prepended with bash. I thought this means bash is launched regardless of shell=False. Finally, are you saying to add `signal.signal()` to `path.to.module`? Not sure how that would help since it's not detecting incoming signals

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment, it is now working with the top form but having added signal.signal() to `path.to.module`. Thanks!